# Why don't some if/else statements use the curly {} brackets?

Tags: java, if-statement, processing, brackets, curly-braces

I have a serious question that's been bugging me for the longest time now. I've recently been assigned to do the Logic-1 > alarmClock on CodingBat and I came up with this code as my solution:

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
  if (!vacation) {
    if (0 < day && day != 6) {
      return "7:00";
    } else {
        return "10:00";
      }
  } 
  
  if (vacation) {
    if (0 < day && day != 6) {
      return "10:00";
    } else{
      return "off";
    }
  }
   
}
```

When I go to run this code I keep getting this message saying "Compile Problems: missing return statement line:18." After tweaking the code and trying other solutions I gave up and eventually asked a friend how they solved the code to which they showed me this code:

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
  if (!vacation) {
    if(0 < day && day != 6)
      return "7:00";
    else
      return "10:00";
  } else if (day > 0 && day != 6)
      return "10:00";
    else
      return "off";
    
}
```

He gave me a few suggestions but the one I 've been curious about is why the second example doesn't have the curly brackets. I was taught that an if statement was to have the curly brackets to contain the body of code within the block and at this point I'm confused why the second code doesn't have any curly brackets next to some of the if/else statements.

Comment: Because there is no need for it, in the Java language.  Braces (not "curly brackets", that's just baby talk) are required when there are multiple statements controlled by the if/else, or possibly to resolve dangling-else ambiguity, but not generally otherwise.  Some people will tell you that you should **always** use the superfluous braces; I disagree.  Use them if they add clarity.

Comment: that is not related to having or not the `{}`, but using `else` or not

Answer (score 1):

Look closely the 1st example.
You have 1 method and all the return statements are used inside of some if blocks.

```
{
    if ()
    {
        return 
    }
    
    if ()
    {
        return
    }
}
```

Whats the problem over there? What would happen if these two if are false? What actually the method will return? You are missing a 3rd return statement there... just before the last '}'.

So, lets go to the 2nd example. You have 1 if statement with condition, 1 else if and finally the 'else' check.

```
{
    if ()
    {
        return 
    }
    
    else if ()
    {
        return
    }
    else
        return
}
```

It is covering all the scenarios in this case with the else check.

To understand that imagine this one:

```
private static String getDayName(int day)
{
    if (day == 1) {
        return "Monday";
    }
    
    if (day == 2) {
        return "Tuesday";
    }
    
    // What would returned if the day is equal to 3?
}
```

So, your code should cover all scenarios. With some changes, you can avoid the extra checks like that:

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation){
    if (0 < day && day != 6){
        return vacation ? "10:00" : "7:00";
    }
    
    return "off";
}
```

P.s I'm not sure about the day checks, i used your condition instead of the second example

Answer (score 1):

When you replace `if (vacation)` with `else` every control flow returns a value. In fact **it is a compiler limitation**: it sees `if (vacation)` and assumes that when the condition does not hold (the *else* so to say), you reach the end of the method without a `return` of a value.

The compiler is not so clever that in that case the first `if (!vacation)` will have caused a return with value.

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
    if (!vacation) {
        if (0 < day && day != 6) {
            return "7:00";
        } else {
            return "10:00";
        }
    } else {
        if (0 < day && day != 6) {
            return "10:00";
        } else {
            return "off";
        }
    }  
}
```

The code assumes a day value 0 .. 6, with 0 probably Sunday and 6 proably Saturday. The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum is nicer.
`DayOfWeek.getValue()` will deliver the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).

```
public String alarmClock(DayOfWeek day, boolean vacation) {
    if (!vacation) {
        return switch (day) {
               case SATURDAY, SUNDAY -> "10:00";
               default -> "7:00";
               };
    } else {
        return switch (day) {
               case SATURDAY, SUNDAY -> "off";
               default -> "10:00";
               };
    }  
}
```

The *switch expression* is relatively new, but is ideal here.

(You could also keep in mind the localized [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html).)

Comment: maybe the compiler is "*so clever*" to not assume that `vacation` cannot be changed (however¹) in between both `if` statements.... || **¹** not trivial, since it is a local variable/parameter... but maybe weaving like in AspectJ or I believe some mocking framework) || at the end it is just how it is specified...

Answer (score 0):

When there will be only one statement for any block (if,else,any loop etc.), then use of {} becomes optional. If there will be multiple statements, then we will have to use {}.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one statement, you don't need to use `{` and `}`. But it can be dangerous. Apple had this problem in the past.